# Launch google navigation app in android without voice assistance

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation

I am trying to launch goole navigation from my android app. And it is successfully launching the navigation app.

```
   String uri;
           uri = "google.navigation:q="
                + lat + ","
                + lo
                + "&mode=d";

        Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse(uri);
        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
        mapIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
        if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(mapIntent);
}
```

But is launching with voice assistance.

My requirement is launching google Navigation app without voice assistance.
Please help me on this

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot change the behavior of other apps to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The voice assistance is a part of the Google Navigation App. Once the app is launched then the user can choose to mute, unmute, or hear alerts. You can only choose to open the app. You will have no control over its internal working

For more details on how to mute, unmute, or hear alerts : [Use navigation in the Google Maps app](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3273406?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)